# (eval):1 parse error near 'then'

Tags: oh-my-zsh

I am getting an error of (eval):1 parse error near 'then' when I used zsh's command 'source .zshrc'.

```
~ source .zshrc
(eval):1: parse error near `then'
```

this is my .zshrc file:

```
export ZSH=/Users/chourongqishi/.oh-my-zsh
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home
export
PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}:${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}:${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}
/platform-tools:${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/tools:${JAVA_HOME}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/chourongqishi/Library/Android/sdk/platform-
tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/chourongqishi/Library/Android/sdk/tools
plugins=(git)
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
source ~/.bash_profile
alias cls='clear'
alias -s html=subl
alias -s txt=subl
alias -s java=subl
alias -s xml=subl
```

Comment: The error must comes from files in `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
source ~/.bash_profile`. Bash profile is a bash file, you are trying to execute it in zsh. Mistake.

Comment: Thank you! I removed the 'source ~/.bash_profile' . Solved the problem.

Comment: I made a proper answer for you to approve ;-)

Answer (score 6):

The error comes from the `source` directive which you use. The `source` directive will execute the files they are provided, within the context of the current script.

You use `source ~/.bash_profile`. This file is a bash script, you are trying to execute it in zsh.

This is where your problem comes from: ensure you do not import files made for other shell programs.