# Question: (eval):1 parse error near 'then'

Tags: oh-my-zsh

I am getting an error of (eval):1 parse error near 'then' when i open the terminal.
I have seen the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45473868/eval1-parse-error-near-then) but my question still exist.

here is my .zshrc file:

```
if [[ -r "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh" ]]; then
  source "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh"
fi

export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"

HB_CNF_HANDLER="$(brew --repository)/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-command-not-found/handler.sh"
if [ -f "$HB_CNF_HANDLER" ]; then
source "$HB_CNF_HANDLER";
fi


ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"

DEFAULT_USER="martin"
POWERLEVEL9K_MODE='nerdfont-complete'
prompt_context() {
   if [[ "$USER" != "$DEFAULT_USER" || -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ]]; then
     prompt_segment black default "%(!.%{%F{yellow}%}.)$USER"
   fi
}

plugins=(command-not-found you-should-use git zsh-autosuggestions git-open)  

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

source ~/powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k.zsh-theme

[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

export PATH=“$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH”
eval “$(pyenv init -)”

typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_INSTANT_PROMPT=quiet
```